# How can I export transposed excel table to word?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and it doesn’t work like it is supposed to

Background: excel table with header and five rows

Task: create word file of header and one row as single table, repeat as many times as there are rows, display them all one below another one, have all borders, transpose so header from excel becomes first column

```vb
Sub mkDocWithBorders()
    Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, rng As Range, x As Long, y As Long, i As Long
    Dim a As Long, c As Long
    Dim wApp As Object, wDoc As Object, wTbl As Object
   
    ' Set references to workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(1)
   
    ' Find the last used row and column in the worksheet
    x = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    y = sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count
   
    ' Set the range to include all used cells in the worksheet
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(x, y))
   
    ' Create a Word application and document
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.Visible = True
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add
   
    ' Loop through rows in the Excel range and create tables in Word
    For i = 1 To x
        ' Add a new paragraph before each table
        If i > 1 Then
            wDoc.Paragraphs.Add
        End If
       
        ' Create a new table with 1 row and y columns
        Set wTbl = wDoc.Tables.Add(wDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range, 1, y)
       
        ' Format the table with all borders
        With wTbl
            .Borders.Enable = True
            For a = 1 To y
                .Cell(1, a).Range.Text = rng.Cells(i, a).Value
            Next a
        End With
    Next i
   
    ' Release object references
    Set wTbl = Nothing
    Set wDoc = Nothing
    Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: "it doesn’t work like it is supposed to" - in *what exact way* does it not work like you want?

Answer (score 0):

There is no description of the problem you are getting, so the response is based on a guess.

These rows does not do what the comment says:

```
' Find the last used row and column in the worksheet
x = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
y = sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

It might be correct, if the first cell in use is A1. Otherwise it'll be the number of rows and columns used, not the last.
If that's the case, the replace

```
Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(x, y))
```

with

```
Set rng = sht.UsedRange
```